# Inserting a ref value into an object table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an assignment for college and I'm having trouble doing one of my inserts.
I have created an object called memeber

```
CREATE TYPE memeber AS OBJECT
(
  member_id INTEGER,
  member_name VARCHAR(30),
  member_jobtitle VARCHAR(30),
  member_skills  skills_list,
  past_projects  past_projects_NTT
)
```

Then I created this object table

```
CREATE TABLE project_resources of MEMEBER 
(
  MEMBER_ID PRIMARY KEY,
  MEMBER_NAME NOT NULL
)NESTED TABLE past_projects STORE AS PROJ_EXT;
```

Then I had to create an object called project as follows

```
CREATE TYPE project as OBJECT
(
  PROJECT_ID  INTEGER,
  PROJECT_ASSIGNED_MEMBER REF MEMEBER,
  PROJECT_TITLE VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

I had to create an object table of type project and alter it

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT_TABLE OF PROJECT;

ALTER TABLE PROJECT_TABLE ADD PRIMARY KEY(PROJECT_ID);

ALTER TABLE PROJECT_TABLE ADD (CONSTRAINT NULL_CHK CHECK(PROJECT_TITLE IS NOT NULL);
```

No this is where I start to have trouble, I have been shown how to insert values to a table when all the values are of type ref, but when I include the other types I'm unsure of the syntax.

This was my attempt:

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT_TABLE 
SELECT 1, REF(M)
FROM MEMEBER M
WHERE M.MEMBER_ID =1, 'KING KONG';
```

Could someone shed some light on the syntax for me please?

Comment: What database are you using? Is it Oracle?

Comment: I'm using Oracle, sorry should have tagged that.

Comment: Only a typo I think:  `SELECT 1, REF(M), 'KING KONG' FROM ...` (you put `'KING KONG'` at the far end of the query by mistake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research I found the solution:

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT_TABLE
(PROJECT_ID,
PROJECT_ASSIGNED_MEMBER,
PROJECT_TITLE)VALUES(
2,
(SELECT REF(M) FROM project_resources M WHERE M.member_id = 2),
'Bomb');
```